# Comparing two asymptotic growth rate of two functions

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

I have a hard time comparing the two functions:

```
n^(0.001n)
n!
```

Any insights?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace n with a few number, for example

0 10 10^6 10^15 and compare the results of thoses functions. It should give you an idea of which one grow faster.